# Largrange Multiplier KKT condition problem

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let's say with the constraint function $$g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1 > 0, $$ I am maximizing $$f(x,y) = x + y -1 .$$ Intuitively, since the constraint function does not provide a finite constrained region, there is no solution, and $f(x,y)$ can infinitely increase.

However, if I just plainly proceed with Lagrange multiplier calculation, 
$$L(x,\lambda) = (x + y -1) +\lambda(x^2 + y^2 -1)$$
I get
$$y,x = -\sqrt{2}/2, \lambda = 1/\sqrt{2}$$
And this still satisfies KKT conditions 
$$g(x) \geq 0 , \lambda \geq      0, \lambda g(x) = 0.$$

I expected that I would have some result that conflicted KKT conditions, but nothing was violated.

Does this mean that Lagrange multiplier under KKT condition can produce a solution that cannot be solved, without giving any indication of intractability?

Comment: KKT condition are only necessary but not sufficient...

Comment: Hmm, then should I know if the problem is solvable using Lagrange multiplier in advance? If functions are complicated, what's the systematic way to confirm that the optimization with inequality conditions is solvable using Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: There are second order sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lagrange's method finds the conditionally stationary points of $f$ on the unit circle $S^1$. That's all. Whether these points give rise to a global min or max of $f$ on the feasible set $\bigl\{(x,y)\>\bigm|\, x^2+y^2\geq1\bigr\}$ is a totally different matter. This has to be discussed in a subsequent analysis of the overall findings.

To give an example: If the problem would have been to find the min of the function$g(x,y):=x^2-x y+2y^2$ on the same feasible set, then the points found by Lagrange's method would be useful.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much!